# How do I install a shared library?

Tags: linux, libraries

I have tried multiple solutions for this problem that already exists, and nothing I do seems to work. It seems like it should be working from everything that I can observe, but the binary I'm trying to run just can't seem to find the library no matter what I do.

[image]

Edit: Removed the file from the end of the path, and still getting the same results.

[image]

For what it's worth, the library shows up multiple places in the system, and I imagine that it is working as intended for that software since they all run as expected, but even with the path set properly it can't seem to find the library.

Comment: As the name suggests `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is a collection of `:` separated library-paths. Remove the `libpng12.so.0` from `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` & try.

Comment: hint; `echo "$PATH"` => path1:path2:path3 --- no filenames in there.

Comment: What is _umodel_? How did you install it? Why are you trying to use a shared library from Steam? // Please do not post text as images. Instead copy the contents and put it in a code block.

Comment: Sorry, will post as text from now on, haven't used this website very much. umodel is software for viewing Unreal Engine files, I'm trying to make a mod for an Unreal Engine 4 game. I downloaded the binary from here and added it to usr/bin/. https://www.gildor.org/en/projects/umodel#files I'm using it from steam because it happens to already be installed there, among about ten other places, and installing it using advice found here didn't improve my situation. https://askubuntu.com/questions/895897/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libpng12-so-0

Comment: Okay, so this software is a little strange. It’s compiled as a static executable but still using some libraries. Your best bet might be to just compile it yourself, it doesn’t look terribly complicated.